# Передача данных в отображение. CodeIgniter.

Tags: php, codeigniter

При передаче объекта в отображение пишет, что была использована неизвестная переменная.
Функция:

```
$this->load->database();
$boards = $this->db->query('SELECT name FROM boards');
      $this->load->view('board', $boards);
```

Отображение:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo $boards['name'];
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bump, bump.

Comment: @NyaXA вы не хотели бы потрудиться оформить код перед бампами?

Comment: Не оформляется.

Comment: Bump, bump.

Answer (score 1):

[@NyaXA](/users/13389/nyaxa), если вы передаете в функцию переменную под названием boards - функция не догадается внутри, что снаружи переменная называлась boards. Скорее всего там extract() и ваши данные валяются под какой-нибудь переменной типа ${0} или $name.

Comment: И что теперь делать?

Comment: Я бы начал с документации. Но есть вероятность, что
    $this->load->view('board', array('boards' => $boards));
успешно сработает (в этом случае внутри шаблона переменной boards действительно будет присвоена "внешняя" переменная boards). Но я не знаю точно, как оно там работает в CI.

Comment: Всё - равно не видит.
Однако, теперь нужно обращаться к переданным данным как к объекту. Хотя, изначально, так и должно было быть.

Comment: Это уже вопрос как из БД выгружаются данные

Comment: Дело в том, что это не первый раз.
Данные то передаются, то нет. Фреймворк, вроде, хороший. Но этим просто выбешивает.

Comment: @NyaXA, поверьте, несмотря на всю непредсказуемость PHP, проблемы с форматом и передачей данных - это проблемы недостаточной осведомленности разработчика. Любой адекватный фреймворк имеет четкие форматы на входе и выходе функций, методов, классов, модулей и пр.

Comment: В документации сказано: передать вторым параметром данные и в отображении к ним можно обращаться как к объектам. Не исключаю и того, что я - рак.

Comment: фреймворк самый простой и очень хороший
но все равно надо читать документацию как минимум.
Ну и тутториалов по этому фреймворку больше чем по любому другому.
Посмотрите как там делают.
Хотите напишу код за вас но это не интересно попробуйте сами.